# Using fopen() method in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get all the files in a given url location.

Example: consider this url - http://www.test.com/test/
I have three files(file1.txt, file2.csv, file3.xls) inside the test folder on the given url. How can I read the file names using the fopen() method in PHP?

Comment: You can't list files from a URL like you can from a filesystem folder.  You would have to parse the directory index that the web server shows (if there is one); it's going to be in HTML format though

Comment: The possibility to do what you want depends on whether HTTP server that serves the URL is configured to return directory indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on ability of HTTP server, that handles your URL, to return directory indexes.  Even when it able to return indexes, format of such index is not standardized.  If you know that HTTP server returns directory indexes and you know the format, you can get list of files like this:

```
$index = fopen ('http://ftp.gnu.org/', 'r');
$data = "";
while ($d = fread ($index, 65536))
  $data = $data . $d;

$matches = array ();
preg_match_all ('/href="([^"]+)"/', $data, $matches);

print_r ($matches [1]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also match any sort `href` on the page? (as well as the links on the top)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Sure, but automatically generated directory index usually does not contain much unrelated links.  If it does, you need to filter them out somehow.  This, again, depends on the format of directory index for particular server which is not standardized.

Comment: Hi Mikhail... Thank you for your reply. And I got a good result from you code snippet. Following is the output which I received.

Array ( [0] => ?C=N;O=D [1] => ?C=M;O=A [2] => ?C=S;O=A [3] => ?C=D;O=A [4] => /test1/test2/data/ [5] => Attendance%20(another%20copy).txt [6] => Attendance%20(copy).txt [7] => Attendance.csv )

Actually I have three files inside the data folder. Those three files I can see from the elements 5,6 and 7 in the above array. But I wonder why this array has some additional elements(0,1,2,3 and 4). Can you please explain the reason for this?

Comment: Just open `http://ftp.gnu.org/` in browser and you will see the answer.  You need to find some way to filter out unrelated links, and this method depends on server your are connecting.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're wanting is a list of files in a certain directory then instead of `fopen()` try [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php):

```
$dir = "http://www.test.com/test/"

$files = scandir($dir);

print_r($files);
```

If the host server permissions allow it, you should get a result of:

```
Array(
[0] => .,
[1] => ..,
[2] => file1.txt,
[3] => file2.csv,
[4] => file3.xsl
)
```

Then you could always cycle through the array to make a `<ul>` of the result, or however else you'd like the content to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt. But your method did not work for me. This I tested in localhost.

Comment: Have you also tried using the relative path? For example: `$dir = "/test/";` with the same following code? Relative path works on my localhost